# How do I undo a checkout in git?

Tags: git

I just checked out an earlier commit from my local git repo. I haven't made any changes to it, I was just looking at it. Now I want to go back to my latest commit - how do I do that?

The exact command I used to check it out:

```
git checkout e5dff6b3c5d704f9b598de46551355d18235ac08
```

Now when I type git log, at the top I see this checked out commit, but none of my later commits. Did I accidentally delete those?

Comment: I think you're seeing it the wrong way: we checkout to branches (heads), not commits individually

Answer (score 250, accepted):

Try this first:

```
git checkout master
```

(If you're on a different branch than `master` (or `main`), use the branch name there instead.)

If that doesn't work, try...

For a single file:

```
git checkout HEAD /path/to/file
```

For the entire repository working copy:

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

And if that doesn't work, then you can look in the reflog to find your old head SHA and reset to that:

```
git reflog
git reset --hard <sha from reflog>
```

`HEAD` is a name that always points to the latest commit in your current branch.

Comment: but how do I view my commits to decide which SHA1 hash to give it?

Comment: You don't - you type `HEAD`, verbatim. Git already knows what `HEAD` means. However, if you really, really wanted to give it a SHA1 instead, you could use `git log` to look at the commit log.

Comment: when I run `git reset --hard HEAD` it brings me back to that checked out commit... I'll post the exact command I used to check it out.

Comment: (If you're curious, you can type `git rev-parse HEAD` and see that it gives you a SHA1 corresponding to your latest commit.)

Comment: I've added two new options above, try them (in order - try the checkout version first).

Comment: From your edit, it looks like what you actually did was check out a full revision, which doesn't get rid of your branch - it actually treats it as a separate checkout, unrelated to your branch. `git checkout master` (or your branchname instead of `master`) should get you back to where you need to be.

Comment: hehe `git reflog` and `git reset --hard <sha from reflog>` worked PERFECTLY. thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Amber: You might want to move `git checkout master` up to the top of the answer - since the OP checked out an SHA1 directly, HEAD was clearly detached, so that's probably the most helpful thing for others finding this question.

Answer (score 96):

To undo `git checkout` do `git checkout -`, similarly to `cd` and `cd -` in shell.

Comment: Did you mean to emphasize `git checkout` with no arguments? `git checkout -` gives an error.

Comment: `git checkout -- .` works a lot better, for me.

Comment: git checkout - worked for me

Comment: @Mort `git checkout -- .` modifies the workspace without changing branches, whereas `git checkout -` switches your branch.

Answer (score 18):

You probably want `git checkout master`, or `git checkout [branchname]`.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using github, chances are the name for default branch is no longer `master`. Try `git checkout main` instead.

Comment: Come on! This question was ASKED 10 years, 9 months ago (at the time I am writing this comment). The default branch was `master` at that time. And the question is not related to checking out to a non-existing branch. :D

Comment: This could be very relevant to someone who is reading this today. I don't understand why thread necromancers get such a bad rep. Just because the post is old doesn't mean no one will ever read it again. If it did then what would be the point of even keeping these old questions up?