# Git Checkout -f to undo all local changes sets back to initial commit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I messed up on my rails app so I used the command:

```
$ git checkout -f
```

to go back to my previous commit and get rid of my screw ups. After research I see that this command undos all local changes! Now my app is showing the initial commit of the project in Firefox and I cannot seem to get it back to the latest commit and show all of the work that I have done so I can test it in my browser. I have tried three of the tactics in this post [How do I undo a checkout in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601911/how-to-undo-a-checkout-in-git)

```
$ git reset --keep

$ git checkout master

$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

but I still am seeing the application as it was when I first started the project. When I type in...

```
git status
```

terminal shows that I am on branch master. I am still seeing all the commits when running git reflog. How can I get my application back so that I actually see all the local changes and can keep testing the app in my browser?

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you know what the reflog is and how to view it. Pick the latest commit that you want to keep from the reflog, and:

```
git reset --hard abc123
```

where `abc123` is the SHA1 of the commit you want. That will update `master` (your current branch) to the commit `abc123`, along with all the history implied by that..

Comment: Its weird... I just tried this '$ git reset --hard c13a3d3' and the result I get in terminal is what I would expect
'HEAD is now at c13a3d3 Added users...' which is the latest commit. But when I go to my application in the browser I still see a very old version of my project. Is this a git bug? I am using git version 1.7.4.4 on Mac OSX 10.7.2. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: I would first check that the files in your Git working directory appear as you expect them to be. The problem you're seeing is unlikely to be a Git bug; it's more likely to be some step that you've forgotten to do that you normally do to compile/build/deploy/whatever your code.