# Forgot to push and lost changes

Tags: git, git-svn

Git is configured on my local machine. I
 used the following commands

```
git add .
git commit -m "message "
```

yesterday and forgot to push. I made several changes yesterday. Today due to some problem I am not able to `push`. I don't know what happened today morning, but all my code went away.

**Which commands do I need to get my code back?**

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you try to push? What error messages?

Comment: `git reflog` gives SHA1 of recently created commits. BTW error message of 'some problem' could help us understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have committed your code (which is now gone), you can check [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

It will list any unreferenced commit, for you to get back.
See for instance "[Undoing `git reset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2510276/6309)", or "[how to undo a checkout in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601927/6309)".