# Revert / Undo Git Rebase onto in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, rebase

Today I have come with a issue that accidently happened with me.

For my current project, I have two local branches in my studio.

**Local Branches :**

a) master (passive branch)

b) Account (active branch)

and the same on the Remote Server as well.

Yesterday I pushed my local Account branch to Remote.

**My Problem :**

First I checkout to local master branch and then I clicked on local Account branch and clicked on **Rebase onto**... :(

And now my both the branch shows the same files and directory structure.

***Android Studio is showing messages like***

a)Gradles project sync failed.(Basic functionality will not work)

b)Module SDK is not defined.

In every file all the imported modules and library's are showing errors.

I read about Rebase but I am not clear about what it did in my case.

**My Questions :**

What can I do to revert it back to normal ?

I can't understand, why both the branches are getting the same gradle messages.

Whether it affected to my remote files as well ?

Can I do a Revert from Local History ?

Comment: BTW, What's wrong with the question ?

Comment: Can anyone shed some light on my questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do. First off, open the VCS tab in Android Studio.

At the top of the bar, you'll see that it says log:

[image]

Right-click on any given revision and select "checkout revision". This does then use the [checkout command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).
 Example usage on [reverting from the commandline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601911/how-do-i-undo-a-checkout-in-git)

Alternatively, you can use the revert button:

[image]

But you can only revert to the last commit using it, so if you want to go back further it's easier using the first method

And no, you cannot revert using local history. This is file specific history and not VCS history. A single invalidate caches and restart wipes this history, so it isn't reliable to use. Using VCS is better for these cases, especially when you have Git already installed and active in the project

Comment: This is what I wanted , Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you mess up the rebasing process for example accepting something you do not want to and end up with something like this:

[image]

There is a possibility of aborting the whole rebase process from Git>Rebase> Abort Rebase:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can do this in Android studio but definite can on the console. Check `git reflog` (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

You can type in `git reflog` and check at which point you want to revert to then type in `git reset 'HEAD@{1}`. (replace `HEAD@{1}` based on the output of `git reflog`.

Comment: You don't have to be an expert in git command line to do this. Just open up your command line and go to your repository's directory and type `git reflog`.

Comment: I will try that but i was thinking if I could do it with studio, Can't I use the Revert option in Local history for this.

Comment: @AshishShukla local history isn't VCS history

Answer (score 0):

There are some options in VCS menu -> Git sub menu include abort rebase to undo rebase. other options are skip and continue rebase.