# How to recover all deleted local files which were deleted using command (Git checkout ...)?

Tags: git, vcs-checkout

I had a project which I wanted to push to Git. So I create a local repo (`git init`). I had a `.gitignore` in remote repo so I couldn't push my local files to remote. So I did `git checkout origin/master`, and all my local files are gone.

Is there any way to recover them?

Here's what I have done:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push origin master (failed)
git checkout origin/master
```

Comment: Before committing changes, on which branch you were?

Comment: this was the first time i wanted to push changes so remote doesn't contain any code. on master

Comment: `.gitignore` doesn't necessarily have anything to do with a failed push.  Can you include the entire error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `git commit -m "Initial commit"` step actually completed successfully, then your local `master` should have all your work.  You may switch to that branch to verify this:

```
git checkout master
```

I don't know why you thought to checkout `origin/master`.  This is the remote tracking branch, and it doesn't really have anything to do with your current problem.  You need to resolve the reason why your pushes are being rejected.

Comment: i already found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601911/how-do-i-undo-a-checkout-in-git. all i had to do was ```git checkout -```!
i don't know how ```git checkout master``` would help cause now it say ```Already on 'master'```

Comment: @user3132457 If you did `git checkout origin/master` then you certainly were _not_ on `master`.  Basically, it sounds like you don't understand Git.

Comment: if i understood it well, i wouldn't do ```git checkout origin/master``` at first place. in question post i wrote all the commands i've done. so on which branch were i (based on that)?

Comment: As I mentioned, `origin/master` is a tracking branch, and yes you probably didn't want to checkout this branch.  My answer gets you back to the right branch.