# How to return to repository w/out working files (e.g. bare) for compact storage (undo a checkout in git)?

Tags: git, git-bare

Note:
*In the title of the question I put **e.g.**, not **i.e.**: the goal is compact storage, not bare repo which is one particular case of that as I've found out seeking the answer.*

I've cloned a repository from github, I want to store sources just in case. Used solution from [How to clone all remote branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67699/how-to-clone-all-remote-branches-in-git/7216269#7216269):

```
git clone --mirror "$1" "$2"/.git
cd "$2"
git config --bool core.bare false
```

As a result had only `.git` with several dozen files. I wanted to see contents, did `git checkout` (result - thousands of files), now I want to undo and return to compact storage. Neither answers from [How do I undo a checkout in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601911/how-do-i-undo-a-checkout-in-git) not web search helped. Naively deleting all checked out files resulted in git registering deletion of files, I want to return to nice initial repository. Workaround would be to backup `.git` before checkout, but I hope there is a "git way" to return to bare repository.

Added 1:

I followed suggestion of duplicate question ([How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one)). Also guessed

```
git config --bool core.bare false
```

needs to be run afterwards to be able to run checkout later right away as before. Answer

```
git clone [ --bare | --mirror ] path_to_current path_to_clone
```

looks like working, but loses link to original remote. The other one (moving `.git` contents to new empty folder and then running git `config --bool core.bare true` results in following issue:

Original:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
```

"Restored"

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Also:

```
$ git checkout master
D   .github/workflows/ccpp.yml
$ ls -a
.  ..  .git
```

Checkout results in empty folder, I cannot see source code I'm interested in.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one)

Comment: @mkrieger1, please see my updated answer and write what you think about it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

After some reading of first suggested duplicate question and then man pages of git commands, I as of now think the following does what I want:

```
git switch --orphan some_name # e.g. "empty" name
```

As a result I get files disappear from my working folder, it is again nice and compact. I have not tested updating repo from remote, but do not see how that additional branch can add problems. BTW it is not listed in output of `git branch`.

*TL;DR*

I've read top answers from suggested duplicate question ([How to convert a normal Git repository to a bare one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199897/how-to-convert-a-normal-git-repository-to-a-bare-one)). Answer to clone to new empty folder:

```
git clone --bare | --mirror path_current path_clone
```

seems working (but as noted in comments does not preserve configs, e.g. `remote.origin.url=`), just

```
git config --bool core.bare false
```

needs to be run afterwards to move it to same state as original repo (to be ready for checkout).

The accepted one however (moving `.git` contents to new empty folder and then running git `config --bool core.bare true`) results in the issue I noted in *Added 1* of the question.

Comment: Why do you set `core.bare` to `false` when you want a bare repository?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I guess I want it in the status it was before checkout. In case I forget about `bare` specifics, I can copy to temp location and make checkout, but is is still compact.  I maybe using incorrect terminology. What is the name/status when no folders are present except `.git`?

Comment: It's a bare repository.

Comment: @ mkrieger1 then doing `git config --bool core.bare false` retains repo in bare state (at least on my PC). Why I did that I explained in previous comment. The issue is not completely closed for me as: see P..S. of the answer.